# are instructions coded wisely in that leap year program in c++?

Tags: c++

i just have wondered that i am correct in that code or not for these instructions? Thank youu.

There are 3 criteria that must be taken into account to identify a leap year:

If the year can be evenly divided by 4 then it is a leap year, however…
If that year can be evenly divided by 100, and it is not evenly divided by 400, then it is NOT a leap year.
If that year is evenly divisible by 400, then it is a leap year.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  int year;
  std::cout << "Please enter the year:";
  std::cin >> year;
  if(year % 4 == 0) {

      std::cout << "It is leap year.";
  } else if ( year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0){
    std::cout << "It is not a leap year";
  } else if ( year % 400 == 0) {

    std::cout << "It is a leap year";
  } else {

    std::cout << "Sorry! it is not a leap year";
  }
  
  
  
}
```

Comment: See what happens when `year` is `1900`.

Comment: We are SO lucky that 2000 was divisible by 400.  Do you know how many programs would have gotten dates wrong for that year?

Answer (score 1):

No, your order is backward. If `year % 4 == 0` is `true`, then you will enter that portion of the `if`-statement. Consider the year `2100`. It is divisible by `4`, so it will go into the `if`, and print that it is a leap year.

Reversing your conditions should solve this:

```
if ( year % 400 == 0 )
    std::cout << "It is a leap year";
else if ( year % 100 == 0 )
    std::cout << "It is NOT a leap year";
else if ( year % 4 == 0 ) 
    std::cout << "It is a leap year";
else
    std::cout << "Sorry! it is not a leap year";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the right logic.

```
if (year % 4 == 0) {
  if (year % 100 == 0){
    if (year % 400 == 0)
     std::cout << "It is a leap year";
    else std::cout << "Sorry! it is not a leap year";
  }
  else std::cout << "It is a leap year";
}
else std::cout << "Sorry! it is not a leap year";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the exceptions to the general rule first, starting with the exception to the exception.
That is,

1. The 400 rule
2. The 100 rule
3. The 4 rule

Or, you can capture it in a single expression and not worry about the order.

```
bool is_leap_year = year % 4 == 0 
                && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
std::cout << (is_leap_year ? “Yes!” : “No...”) << std::endl;
```